# json_encode() Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encoded

Tags: php, json

I am encoding my array into JSON and below is the case in which it gives
Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encoded error

```
$test = ['key' => '6E01400'];
json_encode($test, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I understand it considers 'E' in a key as an exponent and tries to convert into a number something like 6.0 e+1400...I don't know not sure though.

Is there anyway I can avoid that conversion for special case like this one, I really need to use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option here, any clue guys?

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?  Looks like this was fixed in 5.5

I believe this is the bug you're referring to? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64695

Comment: I am using php  5.6.99-hhvm

Comment: Well this is totally weird.  Using HHVM shouldn't have an effect on this.  I don't have HHVM installed so I can't be sure.  But running your code on my local machine (5.6.3) I get no error with the output `string(24) "{ "key": "6E01400" }"` which I think is what you're looking for.  Using PHPfiddle, I get the same result.  But on a couple other PHP sandbox sites I get random results.  Some error with the error you described, others, like my computer and phpfiddle work just fine as expected.  I'm going to do some research.

Comment: Correction I have 5.5.3 not 5.6.3

Comment: Thanks  @Squeegy, appreciate that!

Comment: So, I wasn't able to find anything yesterday.  I'm not sure what's happened but as far as I can tell it works correctly in 5.5.3 and I also tested successfully in 7.0.0  But other versions 5.5+ seem to return false and versions prior to 5.5 throw an error.  Maybe someone else can provide a better solution other than "Upgrade to 7.0"?  Otherwise you really can't use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` without first removing those kinds of values.  Sorry :/

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround for this in PHP 5.5.0 and above so that you can still get JSON to output, but it does rewrite your data.

The `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` option can be set on `json_encode`, if you are getting back a `JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN`. The [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) says that in the case of the NAN or INF value, "0 will be encoded in the place of these special numbers."